# Integrate fb share feature in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to integrate share feature in my site. According to the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/ , for integrating i need to do something like this:

```html
<h1>Sharing using FB.ui() Dialogs</h1>

<p>Below are some simple examples of how to use UI dialogs in a web page.</p>

<h3>Sharing Links</h3>

<div id="shareBtn" class="btn btn-success clearfix">Share Dialog</div>

<p>The Share Dialog enables you to share links to a person's profile without them having to use Facebook Login. <a href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog">Read our Share Dialog guide</a> to learn more about how it works.</p>

<script>
document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    display: 'popup',
    method: 'share',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  }, function(response){});
}
</script>
```

And i made this:

```js
function App() {

    const fbstart = () => {
        FB.ui({
            display: 'popup',
            method: 'share',
            href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
        }, function (response) {
        });

    }
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div id="shareBtn" className="btn btn-success clearfix">Share Dialog</div>

            <p>The Share Dialog enables you to share links to a person's profile without them having to use Facebook
                Login. <a href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog">Read our Share
                    Dialog
                    guide</a> to learn more about how it works.</p>
            <button onClick={fbstart}>Click</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

But, from where should i import `FB` variable, because i get an error that i don't have in my project `FB`.
Question: How to integrate properly this feature in react application?

Comment: @luschn, could you take a look ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include [FB SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart) in your program:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'your-app-id',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v8.0'
    });
  };
</script>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

Also note that you need a Faceboo AppId. If you have not already made an app, you can do so by visiting [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com) and clicking on **My Apps**